# How can I play audio instantly in Java?

Tags: java, audio, music

I know JavaSound API like this:

```
audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
DataLine.Info info = new Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
sourceDataLine.open();
sourceDataLine.start();
floatVoiceControl.setValue(-20);
byte[] buf = new byte[0xFF];
int onceReadDataSize = 0;
```

While `file` is the `File` object.

But when I tried to play some very small audio very frequently (say, the audio played when a small enemy is killed), it blocks my main thread and make the game very slow.
Is there any alternative or workarounds? I prefer something inside the Java's standard library, since I'm developing a game engine based on Swing.

Comment: If you're running blocking methods on the main thread then it will block, that's the whole point of blocking and non-blocking APIs...

Comment: Your code doesn't specify the type/class for the variable `line` - what is it?

Comment: @Pikalek the SourceDataLine. I'm using the Java sound library from standard library, sorry for missing information

Comment: @dot_Sp0T no, I opened a new thread to run the code and it's making my UI thread slow, so I used the word `block`. I'll change it

Comment: @ice1000 please either update your samples on here to show how you run the sound on other threads, or even better provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @dot_Sp0T updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you provide it is not discernible if you run the sound on your main-thread or on a worker thread. I will just assume that you are using a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) or similar so you don't have to expensively create a new thread every time you want to play some sound.

From reading the [Javadoc of the DataLine Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html) I understad that the [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#start()) method you use in line #6 of your codesample initiates some I/O operations for reading the audiodata from the underlying file:

> Allows a line to engage in data I/O.

<sup>Excerpt from the javadoc of the [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#start()) method</sup>

Digging further into the [javax soundAPI sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.java) we find that the implementation of [`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.java#AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream%28java.io.File%29) works with a list of [`AudioFileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/spi/AudioFileReader.html)s for which there are no *known implementations*, which means without knowing what sort of audio-file you're trying to load we cannot reasonably dig any much further.

---

**Conclusion**:

From our research into the APIs and sources, and from your statement that:

> But when I tried to play some very small audio very **frequently**...

<sup>**emphasis** mine</sup>

We can reasonably assume that you're getting limited by I/O operation limitations. You might want to see if you can load the sound-file into the heap and play it from memory instead of playing it from disk.

Comment: Really thanks for your help. I'll mark your answer as accepted since you've provide useful information.

Comment: @ice1000 I hope some of it really helps actually